# Clarification about a particular struct definition in C

Tags: c, struct

I found this structure in the slides of my professor:

```
struct point{
      int x;
      int y;
} p;
```

What does p mean? So far I used only the classical struct like this:

```
struct point{
      int x;
      int y;
};
```

Comment: It's a combination of `struct a { int x; }; struct a p;` shortened to `struct a { int x; } p;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct point{
      int x;
      int y;
} p;
```

defines a variable `p` of type `struct point`

it is same as

```
struct point{
      int x;
      int y;
};
struct point p;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct point{
    int a;
    int b;
}p;
```

This is the same as using `struct point p`

When we use typedef struct p as in

```
typedef struct point{
    int a;
    int b;
}p;
```

We can use p to declare a structure pointer or structure variable later on

To create a structure pointer `p *abc`

To create a structure variable `p xyz`

Comment: What you write is not incorrect. But the question was not related to `typedef`. I would emphasize that you are writing about a different aspect that could look a bit similar but isn't.